# jQuery Submit Post Data Not Changing

Tags: jquery, forms, input, submit

I'm checking the data in a form with jQuery.
However, while the incoming data in a form having trouble.
Not refreshing the data in the following code

```
$("#registerform").submit(function () {
    $.post("dogrula.php", $("#registerform").serialize(), function (data) {
        var hata = data;
        if (hata == "Wrong Number") {
            alert("Yanlış");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The full code

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#bd_year").focusout(function () {
            $.post("dogrula.php", $("#registerform").serialize(), function (data) {
                $("#charNum").text(data).css({ "color": "green", "font-size": "120%", "margin-left": "30%" });
            });
            return false;
        });

        $("#registerform").submit(function () {
            $.post("dogrula.php", $("#registerform").serialize(), function (data) {
                var hata = data;
                if (hata == "Wrong Number") {
                    alert("Wrong Number");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

        $("#cfield_6").keyup(function () {
            var max = 11;
            var len = $(this).val().length;
            if (len >= max) {
                $("#charNum").text(" sayı limiti doldu").css({ "color": "red", "font-size": "120%", "margin-left": "30%" });
            } else {
                var char = max - len;
                $("#charNum").text(char + " sayı kaldı").css({ "color": "black", "font-size": "120%", "margin-left": "30%"});
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

$_Post or Data Messages:

Wrong Code,
True Code,
Not Finding,
Sorry My English is Bad,I hope the right recounted

Comment: Do you get the alert after the form-submit?

Comment: Yes, I want to update the form to send the alert. @cars10

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right, but you might want to try disable caching:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: The problem was continued.

Answer (score 0):

Your success function tests the response but **does not put it into any part of your page**:

```
function(data){
  var hata=data;
  if(hata=="Wrong Number"){
    console.log("Wrong Number"); // less intrusive than alert() ...
    // maybe insert:
    $("#charNum").text(data); // or whatever you want to change on the page
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to trim the data before matching it with "Wrong Number", make sure there are no new line characters or any other characters preceding or after the response data.

A link to the site would be great!